# Bottle of water for shaloch manos

Tags: halacha, food, purim, water, mishloach-manot

Can water be counted as a drink for shalach manos ("sending portions" on Purim) or since it is mere water does it never count as a mana ("portion")? My question would apply to soda as well because many poskim hold soda is like water.

Do any sources discuss this?

Comment: Plausibly, whether or not a drink can count as a manah at all is a machloket girsaot in the gemara. See rabbenu chananel Megillah 7, and compare with Rambam's examples

Answer (score 5):

[Likutei Sichos - Lubavitcher Rabbi Zatzal](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14925&st=&pgnum=261&hilite=) says that one is Yotzei Mishloach Manos with a piece of cake and soda. However regarding water I have so far been unable to find a source that either permits it or prohibits it.

Answer (score 4):

After some research I found:

Rav Eliyashiv in Ashrei Ha'Ish pg 311:5 is quoted as stating: One can fulfill the mitzvah of shaloch manos with two different types of drinks. Flavored soft drinks count. Seltzer does not count, since it does not have a din of a drink. [I would assume water would not count either.]

Rav Shmuel Kamenetsky, in Kovetz Halachos 17:9 states: One does not fulfill shaloch manos with seltzer, because it is like plain water, which has no importance.

Answer (score -1):

"Soda is like water" -- with regards to what? Some hold soda's not *chamar medina*, but there are other halachot with other criteria!

The "food" used for an *eruv techumin* can be anything other than water or salt (but for the yeshivishly frugal, salt **plus** water can be used!-- hence soda should be fine), so it wouldn't surprise me if plain water can't be used for mishloach manos.

Comment: If someone drank soda for zimun I believe the Aruch Hashulchan held it is like water

Comment: One can say the same for water if one drinks it on Yom Kippur they are chayiv so maybe it can be used on purim